# Do nested <aside> blocks have a meaning for SEO?

Tags: seo, html5

I have a portal site that draws content form various places.  Some of this content has already included semantic tags like `<aside>` for ads therein.

If I put this content in an `<aside>` tag, because I'm loading several ads, does that have a meaning / signal for SEO?

```
<aside>
  content text body
  <aside>
    other content
  </aside>
</aside>
```

I understand that SEO is, and forever-will-be, an ever-changing landscape, and hope that there is regardless an answer that is right for this time.

Comment: Markup plays little to no role in actual rankings nowadays... but for semantic purposes you wouldn't want to use aside within aside because the aside is relevant to the article, not relevant to another aside.

Comment: Conceptually, I agree with what you're saying, and I would be glad to know that it has no impact on any page ranking.  I have seen sites with terrible DOM structure have great rank, so I have some implicit agreement with you. I wish you had a link or something else to further assert your answer, and leave it as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: @SimonHayter is perfectly right. It is not the mark-up, it is the content that makes the difference. Search engines only pay particular attention to a few HTML tags and treats them only slightly differently. You already know what they are, title, h1, description, etc. Search engines only care about a few things generally and the rest is semantics. Just make good and simple code that makes sense. Do not complicate it and you should be alright.

Comment: Someone really should write an answer

Comment: Simon and I do know the answer. Mark-up plays no role in SEO with the exception of a handful of tags such as title, h1, and description meta-tag which are treated as being valuable topical clues. Aside from the nesting issue which is not recommended, the mark-up will not make a difference. For what it is worth, we are not all SEO parrots and bring real expertise to the topic based upon research and experience based upon technological expertise which most SEOs do not have. Simon is one you can trust the opinion of.

Comment: ...yet, I cannot click "accept" on a comment.  Feel me? ;)

Answer (score 3):

The concepts of "Semantic Markup" (as in HTML5) AND "Semantic SEO" (as in Search Engine Ranking) are not as similar as one would initially think -- and that leads to a lot of confusion.
When we look at "HTML5's Semantic Markup", we look to `<header>`, `<main>`, `<aside>`, `<footer>`, and other tags that are used to create specific sections of today's webpages. There could be 4 differnt `<header>` tags, or three `<footer>` tags in one page. It all depends on how you utilize the tags for your layout. The premise behind semantics in page markup is that, when done correctly, it allows your page to be enjoyed by everyone. In other words, if I had a vision problem, I would be able to use automation to "read" the page to me. Having a `<strong>` element in the content of your `<main>` section, lets the software know how to "speak" that word or phrase. Semantic Markup isn't difficult to learn, but it is like everything else in life... you have to take the time to learn it to do it well.
When we talk about "Semantic SEO", the concepts twist just a bit. The emphasis is not about making the page accessable to the widest possible audience. SEO is still about acheiving the best rank for your pages. Only now, instead of focusing on short sets of keywords within pages that are sparse on content, more emphasis is given to pages that offer a more in depth analysis of the topic. Search Engine's are using queries to gather data and learn to identify what we are looking for. That is not to say that "Keywords are dead", but the old days of having your desired phrase in your `<title>`, and `<h1>` and 5 times in your content, have faded. A couple of short paragraphs isn't going to cut it anymore. Right now, the best thing you can do for long term ranking is to focusing on making your page be the best page online about the topic you are addressing.